# Não consigo substituir caracteres de uma string para outra - É um bug do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, svelte

Estou tentando fazer um efeito de substituição de uma string por outra, mas sem apagar o conteúdo da primeira por completo. Como se fosse um efeito especial, cada letra de uma string vai se transformando em outra palavra. A principio estou tentando fazer como uma máquina de escrever, mas posteriormente quero fazer de forma aleatória. No entanto, não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, parece que é algum bug.

Eis o código:

```
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let title1 = "Seu lugar de vendas";
    let title2 = "Hub do Software";
    
    var k = 0;
    var speed = 150;

    onMount(() => {
        typeWriter();
    });

    function typeWriter() {
        if (k < title1.length) {
            if (k >= title2.length) {
                title2 += title1.charAt(k);
            }
            title2 = title2.replace(title2.charAt(k), title1.charAt(k));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title2;
            k += 1;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }
    }
```

output:

```
EUGLU SV DEARENDAS
```

Comment: *"não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, parece que é algum bug"* fez debug pra tentar entender o que há de errado?

Comment: Olá Ricardo Pontual, aparentemente não aparece nenhum erro. O Código funciona, mas não funciona, é difícil explicar. Ele automaticamente substitui toda a string e depois faz duas trocas por ela mesma. Quando era para fazer o contrário, manter a primeira string e trocar pela segunda.

Comment: Adicionei a tag [tag:svelte] por conta do evento [`onMount()`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount). Correto?

Comment: > "Debugaras seu codigo" Voce inicializa `temp2` com o texto final, o que causa que ja na primeira chamada a `typeWriter()` o elemento da pagina seja modificado para conter o valor armazenado em `temp2`. Logo, a impressao visual de que nada acontece.

Comment: Não estou inicializando com o texto final, o texto final é "texto aleatorio 1". Mas automaticamente passa para texto aleatorio 1,  deveria receber logo no inicio o mesmo texto que o original, com a diferença do primeiro caracter do texto final. Em seguida é para trocar para o segundo caracter, é isso que diz o código, mas o que acontece é o contrário. Ele troca para o texto final, logo de primeira e depois troca cada caracter do texto final pelos respectivos caracteres do texto original, voltando para o texto final. Por isso acho que está bugado, o que ocorre é diferente do que está escrito.

Comment: Vou editar o código porque achei o erro no meu cógido e corrigi, mas ainda está bugado.

Comment: **Se** eu entendi direito, era só fazer isso: https://jsfiddle.net/tevc5rnL/

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está o código correto para fazer esse efeito:

```
import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let title1 = "Your sales place";
    let title2 = "Software Hub";
    var part = "";
    var k = 0;
    var speed = 150;

    onMount(() => {
        typeWriter();
    });

    function sliceReplace(origin, final, k) {

        part = part.slice(0,k);
        part += final.charAt(k) + origin.slice(k+1);
        return part;

    }

    function typeWriter() {
        if (k < title1.length) {
            if (k >= title2.length) {
                title2 += title1.charAt(k);
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sliceReplace(title2, title1, k);
            k += 1;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }
    }
```